# Laravel eloquent where returns result only for first element in foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a simple `hasMany` relation between order and orderItems. What I'm trying to do is fetch the count of similar order items. This is what I've done:

```
        $orderItems = $order->orderItems();

        $distinctItems = $orderItems->groupBy('item_name')->distinct('item_name')->get();


        foreach($distinctItems as $i){

            $i['count'] = $orderItems->where('item_name', '=', $i->item_name)->count();
        }

        $order['items'] = $distinctItems;
```

However the count is returned for only first order Item and 0 for other items. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've also checked that `where()` returns null for the items except the first one.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is so but instead of `$i['count'] = $orderItems->where('item_name', '=', $i->item_name)->count();`  using `$i['count'] = $order->orderItems()->where('item_name', '=', $i->item_name)->count();` does the work. And explanation would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the collection only, first groupBy item_name and then on each item add count and return new collection which would look something like

```
$orderItems = $order->orderItems()->get();
$order['items'] = $orderItems->groupBy('item_name')->map(function($item) {
    $i = $item->first();
    $i->count = $item->count();
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is more neat (:

Comment: :) always try to use inbuilt functionalities of framework they are only there to help us write neat code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$cnt = array();

foreach($distinctItems as $i){

            $cnt[$i]['count'] = $orderItems->where('item_name', '=', $i->item_name)->count();

        }

print_r($cnt);
```

Comment: Well nothing is changed see my comment above.